# how to summarise (dplyr) colums by retrieving top 10 bigrams (ngrams) per group?

Tags: r, dplyr, n-gram

I have a data frame that looks a bit like this:

```
df <- structure(list(group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1", 
"2"), class = "factor"), text = structure(c(2L, 1L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("hello hi four five", 
"hi hello one two three", "one three four five", "one two three"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("group", "text"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")

df
  group                   text
1     1 hi hello one two three
2     1     hello hi four five
3     2          one two three
4     2    one three four five
```

Now I want to summarise this data frame by retrieving the top (maximum 10) bibrams per group.

Something like this (make_bigrams is an imaginary function):

```
df <- group_by(df, group)
summarise(df, make_bigrams(text))
```

The result should be something like this:

```
  group                          text
1     1 hi_hello, hi_one, hi_two_etc.
2     2      one_three, one_two, etc.
```

I tried functions like the tokenizer of RWeka, but none did wat I intended. Does anyone have an idea? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: cf http://tm.r-forge.r-project.org/faq.html#Bigrams. However, you seem to want every co-occurence, and not only bigrams (for instance hi_one in group one : the two words are never found one after the other).

Comment: that's right, I need every co-occurence. I will check the link.

Comment: I allready tried `ngrams(words(x), 2)` but somehow I could not make that function work properly in a summarise() (dplyr) context.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something you could do for bigrams (ie. "contiguous sub-sequences of length n" where n=2 according to `?NLP::ngrams`).

```
library(tm) # for corpus and dtm; loads NLP
library(dplyr)    
library(tidyr)

df$text <- as.character(df$text)

## numbering documents
df$doc <- factor(1:nrow(df))


corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(df$text))
# function source: tm.r-forge.r-project.org/faq.html#Bigrams
BigramTokenizer <-
  function(x)
    unlist(lapply(ngrams(words(x), 2), paste, collapse = "_"), use.names = FALSE)

## create a Term Document Matrix of bigrams
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(corpus, control = list(tokenize = BigramTokenizer))

## Let's find the most frequent for each group
as.data.frame.matrix(tdm) %>%          # transform to df
  add_rownames() %>%                   # we need the words
  gather(doc,value,-rowname) %>%       # convert to long form
  filter(value != 0) %>%               # remove bigrams not in document
  left_join(df[,c("doc","group")]) %>% # match doc number with group number
  group_by(group,rowname) %>%          # grouping
  summarise(n=sum(value)) %>%          # find out the number of bigrams by group
  arrange(desc(n)) %>%                 # sort the data by most frequently found bigrams
  slice(1:10) %>%                      # select only the 10 most frequent in each group
  summarize(most_frequent_bigrams=paste(rowname,collapse = ", ")) # format this to a single string
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you think I can wrap this is into one function that I can call within the summarise function?

Comment: what do you mean? This solution already useses summarize. If you assign the result to a new data.frame, you can then use it how you want (merge it with your source, etc.)

Comment: I was hoping I could do something like `summarise(df, bigrams=get_top10_bigrams(text))` and that it runs all your code in one function.

Comment: that's tricky. you would have to play with `do` to create the tdm inside a dplyr chain